# Make div take the remaining height

Tags: html, css

Well I'm here because I tried everything I found on this website.
Couldn't figure out how to make the id="content" div take the remaining height, although I've managed to make the footer stick to the bottom.

**CSS**

```
<style>
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    background:transparent url(/Site%201/image/bg/17.jpg) no-repeat top center;background-attachment: fixed;
}
#mainPage {
    width:1099px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color:#fff;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    display:table-row;
}
#content {
    padding-bottom:35px;
    background:#FAFAFA;
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:35px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    display:table-row;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div ID="mainPage" align="center">
    <div id="header">
        <?php 
            $spath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
            $spath .= "/site1/header.html";
            include_once($spath);
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    test
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <?php 
            $spath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
            $spath .= "/site1/footer.html";
            include_once($spath);
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

(Ignore the php part, I included it here to look fancy :DD)

Comment: have you considered [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for layout?

Comment: Nope, is there some sort of tutorial/lesson to that?

Comment: Well, I provided you with a link to get you started. There's also around a billion articles on the internet about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are not looking for a general solution, this jquery helps in this case:

```
var remHeight;
remHeight=$("#mainPage").height()-$("#footer").height()-$("#header").height();
$("#content").height(remHeight);
```

also consider reducing the #content padding if used doctype renders paddings outside of divs.

Answer (score 0):

If both header and footer have fixed height, you could use the CSS calc function.